# Android XML Rotation deformation in some devices

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I'am facing a new problem and i can't figure it out, my custom loading spinner is being deformed while rotating in some devices, i know maybe it's related with screen size but i cant figure whats the problem.

To show i've runned the app in 2 emulators, The nexus 5 and a Tinny LG L3 II.

[image: The problem]

And here it's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360" >
        <bitmap
            android:antialias="true"
            android:filter="true"
            android:src="@drawable/spinner_outer" />
    </rotate>
</item>
```

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:maxWidth="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/moody" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading"
            android:maxHeight="200dp"
            android:maxWidth="200dp"
            android:minHeight="1dp"
            android:minWidth="1dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That could happen because the second device has a low density and the rounding operations make that effect.

Comment: How do you add your spinner to layout? Maybe it is wrong height or ImageView scaleType?

Comment: I will add the layout to the question

Comment: You have android:adjustViewBounds and maxSize settings. Maybe it causes image to be stretched at some screens. Try to fix image dimensions or remove max limits. Also try to use scaleType centerInside

Comment: Did i look to wrong layout part? Should i check ProgressBar section?

Comment: Yes adjustViewBounds it's for the static drawable in the center, you should look to the progress bar

Comment: Did you try to specify progress bar size explicitly and remove max size limitations?

Comment: If its a know there is any workaround?